# how can I convert an array of strings into a dropdown in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner in rails and I have this array of times:

> ["08:30", "09:00", "09:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30",
>   "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30", "15:00",
>   "15:30", "16:00", "16:30", "17:00", "17:30", "18:00", "18:30",
>   "19:00", "19:30", "20:00", "20:30", "21:00", "21:30"]

How can I convert it into a dropdown using `options_from_collection_for_select`. I tried using

`<%= select_tag "start_time", options_from_collection_for_select(@start_time,:id, :name ) %>`

but it returned `"undefined method 'name' for "08:30":String"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming

```
@options = ["08:30", "09:00", "09:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30", "15:00", "15:30", "16:00", "16:30", "17:00", "17:30", "18:00", "18:30", "19:00", "19:30", "20:00", "20:30", "21:00", "21:30"]
```

the code will be

```
<%= select_tag "start_time", options_for_select(@options) %>
```

See the [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like following

```
 <%= f.select :time, options_for_select(MONTHS, @job.time) %>
```

MONTHS => your array